# How to full (with all features - ACL support / Xattr support / xxhash library/ zstd library) install (compiling) rsync v3.2.3 on Mac?

Tags: macos, rsync

I am trying to install rsync 3.2.3 on Mac by compiling it. But, I would like to install with all features. For that, it needs some libraries which in here (https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/INSTALL) does not explain how can I install and/or compile them.

By the way, when I "./prepare-source", I get this message:

make: Nothing to be done for `conf'.

Is this right?

By running "./configure" I get this message:

Configure found the following issues:

- Failed to find openssl/md4.h and openssl/md5.h for openssl crypto lib support.
- Failed to find xxhash.h for xxhash checksum support.
- Failed to find zstd.h for zstd compression support.
- Failed to find lz4.h for lz4 compression support.

See the INSTALL file for hints on how to install the missing libraries and/or
how to generate (or fetch) man pages:
https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/blob/master/INSTALL.md

To disable one or more features, the relevant configure options are:
--disable-openssl
--disable-xxhash
--disable-zstd
--disable-lz4

configure.sh: error: Aborting configure run

So, like I said before, I would like to install all the features (ACL support / Xattr support / xxhash library/ zstd library).

Helps are very apreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone...? Someone...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, install Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

And then execute the following command:

```
brew install xxhash; brew install zstd; brew install lz4; brew install openssl;
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib";
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include";
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc;
```

Try again to execute:
./configure

**UPDATE -- 06/05/2021**

You can try to paste the following script into the terminal and run:

```
cd ~/Desktop;
curl -OL https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/archive/v0.8.0.tar.gz;
tar -xvf v0.8.0.tar.gz;
cd xxHash-0.8.0;
make -j4;
sudo make install;

cd ~/Desktop;
curl -OL https://github.com/lz4/lz4/archive/v1.9.3.tar.gz;
tar -xvf v1.9.3.tar.gz;
cd lz4-1.9.3;
make -j4;
sudo make install;

cd ~/Desktop;
curl -OL https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz;
tar -xvf openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz;
cd openssl-1.1.1k ;
./config;
make -j4;
sudo make install;

cd ~/Desktop;
curl -OL https://github.com/facebook/zstd/archive/v1.5.0.tar.gz;
tar -xvf v1.5.0.tar.gz;
cd zstd-1.5.0 ;
make -j4;
sudo make install;

cd ~/Desktop;
curl -OL https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-3.2.3.tar.gz;
tar -xvf rsync-3.2.3.tar.gz;
cd rsync-3.2.3;
./configure;
make -j4;
sudo make install;

cd /usr/local/bin;
./rsync --version;
```

Finding all the software package source code download url is a tedious job. If you are a "script purist," you can indeed do this. But I think Homebrew can really free the programmer's hands and get rid of the nightmare of "submerged in the ocean of curl and printlog".

How do I know the download url of each package? Google a few days, in the end still have to refer to the Homebrew formulae Code:

xxhash：https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/xxhash#default

lz4: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/lz4#default

openssl1.1: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openssl@1.1#default

zstd: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/zstd#default

Comment: Thank you @Janyee for your attention and answer.

I can indeed use Homebrew even for installing rsync. For learning purposes, is there a way I can install and/or compile all these libraries for rsync? I mean, without using a package manager like Homebrew?

Answer (score 1):

While I think that @Janyee gave the correct answer and should get credited, maybe this helps others that ran into a similar **issue of library linking errors**, too.

Compiling **rsync 3.2.4** *(the same happens for rsync 3.2.3)* on **macOS 10.12.x Sierra** with manual installed external libraries `xxHash`, `zstd`, `lz4`, `openssl`, `popt`, `zlib` *in non standard folders* gave the following **error on `make`**, even though `./configure` reported `rsync 3.2.4 configuration successful`:

```
$ make
awk -f ./daemon-parm.awk ./daemon-parm.txt
awk -f ./mkproto.awk ./*.c ./lib/compat.c daemon-parm.h
In file included from ./rounding.c:20:
./rsync.h:643:3: error: Could not find a 32-bit integer variable
# error Could not find a 32-bit integer variable
  ^
./rsync.h:712:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 size, entries;
        ^
./rsync.h:713:8: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
        uint32 node_size;
              ^
              ;
./rsync.h:719:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 key;
        ^
./rsync.h:803:3: error: Character pointers are not 4 or 8 bytes.
# error Character pointers are not 4 or 8 bytes.
  ^
./rsync.h:816:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 num;
        ^
./rsync.h:817:8: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
        uint32 unum;
              ^
              ;
./rsync.h:833:8: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
        uint32 len32;           /* Lowest 32 bits of the file's length */
              ^
              ;
./rsync.h:992:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 len;              /**< length of chunk of file */
        ^
./rsync.h:993:8: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
        uint32 sum1;            /**< simple checksum */
              ^
              ;
./rsync.h:994:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 chain;            /**< next hash-table collision */
        ^
./rsync.h:1002:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 count;            /**< how many chunks */
        ^
./rsync.h:1003:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 blength;          /**< block_length */
        ^
./rsync.h:1004:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 remainder;        /**< flength % block_length */
        ^
./rsync.h:1013:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 p_size;           /* Largest window size we allocated     */
        ^
./rsync.h:1014:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 p_len;            /* Latest (rounded) window size         */
        ^
./rsync.h:1015:2: error: unknown type name 'int32'
        int32 def_window_size;  /* Default window size                  */
        ^
./rsync.h:1051:8: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
        uint32 rflags;
              ^
              ;
In file included from ./rounding.c:20:
In file included from ./rsync.h:1148:
./byteorder.h:75:8: error: 'inline' can only appear on functions
static inline uint32
       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
Failed to create rounding.h!
make: *** [rounding.h] Error
```

Compiling *without* extra libs worked:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/NonStandardDir/rsync/rsync-3.2.4 --disable-openssl --disable-xxhash --disable-zstd --disable-lz4 --disable-roll-simd --disable-md2man
```

The `config.log` and the `./configure` script output gave hints on missing libraries. Executing `make` generated files like `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/conftest_….crash`. Those reports clearly that the library is searched in the wrong *standard* place: `Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblz4.1.dylib`

That the dynamic libraries `liblz4.1.9.3.dylib`, `libzstd.1.5.2.dylib` and `libxxhash.0.8.1.dylib` were linked incorrectly could also be proofed by:

```
$ otool -L /NonStandardFolder/lz4/lz4-1.9.3/usr/local/lib/liblz4.1.9.3.dylib  
# -> Output: … /usr/local/lib/liblz4.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.9.3)…
```

As `popt`, `openssl` and `zlib` weren't affected, because `--prefix` was set in the `./configure` command, the solution is to recompile the incorrectly linked libs with the right prefix for the destination:

```
$ export PREFIX="/NonStandardFolder/lz4/lz4-1.9.3" && make && make install
```

The mistake was to set `DESTDIR` instead of `PREFIX` while executing the `make` command.

Check the dynamic library again and it should be correctly linked:

```
$ otool -L /NonStandardFolder/lz4/lz4-1.9.3/lib/liblz4.1.9.3.dylib 
# -> Output: … /NonStandardFolder/lz4/lz4-1.9.3/lib/liblz4.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.9.3)…
```

After recompiling the libs `lz4`, `xxHash`, `zstd`, something like the following *(adapt to your folder structure)* should work to compile rsync:

```
$ cd /SourcecodeFolder/rsync/rsync-3.2.4

$ make clean

$ ./configure --prefix=/NonStandardDir/rsync/rsync-3.2.4 --disable-debug --disable-md2man --with-rsyncd-conf=/NonStandardDir/rsync/rsync-3.2.4/configuration/rsyncd.conf --with-included-popt=no --with-included-zlib=no --enable-ipv6 --disable-roll-simd CPPFLAGS="-I/NonStandardDir/openssl/openssl-1.1.1n/include -I/NonStandardDir/lz4/lz4-1.9.3/usr/local/include -I/NonStandardDir/zstd/zstd-1.5.2/include -I/NonStandardDir/xxHash/xxHash-0.8.1/include -I/NonStandardDir/popt/popt-1.18/include -I/NonStandardDir/zlib/zlib-1.2.11/include" LDFLAGS="-L/NonStandardDir/openssl/openssl-1.1.1n/lib -L/NonStandardDir/lz4/lz4-1.9.3/lib -L/NonStandardDir/zstd/zstd-1.5.2/lib -L/NonStandardDir/xxHash/xxHash-0.8.1/lib -L/NonStandardDir/popt/popt-1.18/lib -L/NonStandardDir/zlib/zlib-1.2.11/lib"

$ make

$ make test

$ make install
```